# Preventing the same errors from being sent to the rollbar many times

Tags: javascript, rollbar

The same errors for my Javascript application are repeatedly sent to the rollbar. Is there a way to prevent the same errors from being sent after a certain limit?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best option here is to mute that particular error.

Muted items represent issues that are not currently worth investigating. In the Muted state:

- The item won't appear on the Dashboard
- If the item occurs again, it will remain Muted
- Occurrences count for billing purposes

If you have an item that you consider a non-issue, or otherwise don't plan to do anything about soon, you can Mute it so it stays out of sight.

Muted items are still indexed, searchable, etc. and can be changed back to Active at any time. For this reason, occurrences of Muted items do count for billing purposes. If you need to reduce your usage, you should set a rate limit or filter it before it is sent to Rollbar.

You may also be interested in this page in our documentation:

https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/reduce-noisy-javascript-errors